# Why is this function considered an implementation of a queue?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

these examples come from Learning Python by Mark Lutz. The first function is a recursive function used to traverse a list with arbitrary nesting in order to calculate the sum of elements:

```
def sumtree_rec(L):
    tot = 0
    for x in L:
        if not isinstance(x, list):
            tot += x
    else:
        tot += sumtree(x)
    return tot
```

The second function achieves the same thing, but without recursion:

```
def sumtree_notrec(L):
    tot = 0
    items = list(L)
    while items:
        front = items.pop(0)
        if not isinstance(front, list):
           tot += front
        else:
            items.extend(front)
    return tot
```

I believe I understand how both of these functions work. I traced out how L changes in sumtree_notrec with each iteration over the code body, and it matches up with the output from the book. I also think I understand why the recursion is considered a stack, since every level pushes a call frame onto the runtime stack, and is popped off whenever the call is complete.

What I don't understand is why the recursive function is referred to as a FIFO queue? I looked it up and I feel like I understand what the data structures represent, I just don't see how they apply to this function. I also found this resource which explained a bit about the call stack: https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs8/topics.beta/theStack/02/

For example, if I trace through L in the non recursive function (not actual code, just a representation):

```
L --> [1,[2,[3,4],5],6,[7,8]]
L --> (1) is popped [[2,[3,4],5],6,[7,8]]
L --> [2,[3,4],5] is not popped
L --> [6,[7,8],2,[3,4],5]
```

etc...

Why is this called a queue? What object is 'first in' and then 'first out'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive version is a depth-first search. The non-recursive version is a breadth-first search. In the non-recursive version, the `items` list is treated as a queue. Whenever a list is popped from `items`, the individual elements in that list are added to the end of `items`.

That's the simple definition of a queue: elements are added to the back and removed from the front.